# ForeignCollection initialization in domain class

Tags: java, android, sqlite, ormlite, foreign-collection

I have a domain objects with many-to-many relationship. `Menu` can have many `Categories` and `Category` can be in many `Menus`. `Menu` is responsible for `Categories`.

I have made quite layered design for my application and domain classes are strictly separated from `DAO`-s (I have a special synchronization classes for accessing Factory and Repository classes and keeping relationships in sync) and Application layer (I use services there, for example `AddMenuService` where all the logic resides).

For example I create a `Menu` and `Category` objects. Add this category to menu via special appender class. Then I synchronize objects (validate, check if object exists in database or create a new object, calling other Synchro classes if needed, comparing objects from difference and saving or updating them). Categories can be added only through MenuSyncro.

```
Menu m1 = new Menu("Menu for vegetarians");
Category cat1 = new Category("Drinks");

m1.getAppender().addCategory(cat1);

MenuSyncro ms = new MenuSyncro();
ms.synchronize(menu1);
```

I know that I can use `Dao.getEmptyForeignCollection(String fieldName);`, but is there any way to initialize `ForeginCollection<MenuCategory> categories;` in `Menu` class and `ForeignCollection<MenuCategory> menus;` in `Category` class without to access DAO objects first, because i keep getting `NullReference` exceptions because those collections are not initalized?

### Classes

**Menu.class**

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "MENUS")
public class Menu
{
   private final static String ID_FIELD_NAME = "ID";
   private final static String NAME_FIELD_NAME = "NAME";

   @DatabaseField(generatedId = true, columnName = ID_FIELD_NAME)
   private int id;

   @DatabaseField(columnName = NAME_FIELD_NAME, canBeNull = false, unique = true, useGetSet = true)
   private String name;

   @ForeignCollectionField(eager = false)
   private ForeignCollection<MenuCategory> categories;

   @ForeignCollectionField(eager = false)
   private ForeignCollection<LocationMenu> locations;

   private MenuAppender appender;

   public Menu()
   {
      // for ORMLite
   }

   public Menu(String name)
   {
      this.name = name;
   }

   public int getId() { return id; }
   public String getName() { return name; }
   public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }

   public ArrayList<Category> getCategories()
   {
      ArrayList<Category> categoriesList = new ArrayList<Category>();

      if (categories != null)
         for (MenuCategory menuCategory : categories)
            categoriesList.add(menuCategory.getCategory());

      return categoriesList;
   }

   public ForeignCollection<LocationMenu> getLocations()
   {
      return locations;
   }

   public MenuAppender getAppender()
   {
      if (appender== null)
         appender= new MenuAppender(this);

      return appender;
   }
}
```

**Category.class**

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "CATEGORIES")
public class Category
{
   private final static String ID_FIELD_NAME = "ID";
   private final static String NAME_FIELD_NAME = "NAME";

   @DatabaseField(generatedId = true, columnName = ID_FIELD_NAME)
   private int id;

   @DatabaseField(columnName = NAME_FIELD_NAME, canBeNull = false, unique = true, useGetSet = true)
   private String name;

   @ForeignCollectionField(eager = false)
   private ForeignCollection<MenuCategory> menus;

   public Category()
   {
      // for ORMLite
   }

   public Category(String name)
   {
      this.name = name;
   }

   public int getId() { return id; }
   public String getName() { return name; }
   public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }

   public ArrayList<Menu> getMenus()
   {
      ArrayList<Menu> menusList = new ArrayList<Menu>();

      if (menus != null)
         for (MenuCategory menuCategory : menus)
            menusList.add(menuCategory.getMenu());

      return menusList;
   }
```

}

**MenuCategory.class**

```
   @DatabaseTable(tableName = "MENUS_CATEGORIES")
   public class MenuCategory
   {
      private final static String ID_FIELD_NAME = "ID";
      private final static String MENUS_ID_FIELD_NAME = "MENUS_ID";
      private final static String CATEGORIES_ID_FIELD_NAME = "CATEGORIES_ID";

      @SuppressWarnings("unused")
      @DatabaseField(generatedId = true, columnName = ID_FIELD_NAME)
      private int id;

      @DatabaseField(foreign = true, columnName = MENUS_ID_FIELD_NAME, canBeNull = false, foreignAutoCreate = true, foreignAutoRefresh = true)
      private Menu menu;

      @DatabaseField(foreign = true, columnName = CATEGORIES_ID_FIELD_NAME, canBeNull = false, foreignAutoCreate = true, foreignAutoRefresh = true)
      private Category category;

      public MenuCategory()
      {
         // for ORMLite
      }

      public MenuCategory(Menu menu, Category category)
      {
         this.menu = menu;
         this.category = category;
      }

      public Menu getMenu()
      {
         return menu;
      }

      public void setMenu(Menu menu)
      {
         this.menu = menu;
      }

      public Category getCategory()
      {
         return category;
      }

      public void setCategory(Category category)
      {
         this.category = category;
      }
   }
```

Thanks in advance, evilone

Comment: What are you trying to ask dude?  Are you trying to initialize the collection without using the DAO?  What would happen if you added a category to a menu that didn't have the DAO attached?

Comment: @Gray Yeah, I want to initialize the collection without messing with DAO in the domain class, you are correct. This can be done with NHibernate. Wanted to know if there's some way to do this. If not, then how can I do it using less DAO as possible in domain.

Comment: Can you answer the other question @evilone?  What would happen if you added a category to a menu that didn't have the DAO attached?  Also, how does it work in NHibernate?  How do you initialize the collection there?

Comment: @Gray I don't understand what what you mean by this other question. In Nhibernate I create mapping file in xml (also can do it in class). I initialize collection in domain's class constructor simply calling IList<Object> objects = new List<Object>();. For example http://nhibernate.hibernatingrhinos.com/17/mapping-collections-in-nhibernate-part-1

Comment: Sigh.  I understand _how_ you can do this.  What I would like to know is what I've asked now 2 times in comments.  What would happen if you added a category to a menu that didn't have the DAO attached?  Please answer that question.

Comment: @Gray Well, I add the category to the menu, and start to synchronize menu object. The DAO is going to be attached in syncro. Nothing serious will happen I guess :) In repository class I made one method that checks by id if object is existing or not and then decides what to call (create or update and also refresh in both cases). In syncro I validate incoming objects, check for changes, also call Category syncro if there are some changes in Menu.Category.

Comment: @Gray Right now I cannot add category to the menu :) Because I want to use special add method, but therefore I need initialized collection...Also there's no difference if I add existing category objects, repeating objects etc, this will be take cared in syncro (removing existing and repeating objects)

Answer (score -3):

Just calling `<lazyCollection>.iterator()` should be enough to initialize your collection properly.

Comment: So calling categories.iterator() in Menu.getCategories() doesn't give me NullReference?

Comment: I cannot call iterator(), because ForeignCollection<MenuCategory> categories is null and it creates NullReferenceError.